# Unable to Trust Authorities and Install Plugins in Eclipse - Button for Trusting Selected Authorities Unselectable

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I'm encountering an issue while attempting to install plugins in Eclipse. When prompted to trust authorities during the installation process, I select all of them. However, the button for trusting the selected authorities remains unselectable, preventing me from proceeding with the plugin installation.

I have attached some screenshots showcasing the problem. One of the screenshots includes a selection that, upon clicking, triggers an error. The error message is also included in the screenshot.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully install plugins in Eclipse. Thank you in advance for your assistance.
[Screenshot showcasing the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ozMw.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pbMQo.png)
[Screenshot highlighting the unselectable button for trusting selected authorities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E12Zo.png)

I followed the installation process and reached a step where I had to select authorities to trust. I selected all the authorities as instructed, expecting the button for trusting the selected authorities to become selectable. However, despite making the selections, the button remained unselectable, preventing me from proceeding with the plugin installation.

I tried the following steps:

```
Opened Eclipse and navigated to the plugin installation process.
When prompted to trust authorities, I selected all of them by clicking on each option.
Expected the button for trusting the selected authorities to become selectable.
```

However, what actually happened was that the button remained unselectable, even though I had made the necessary selections. This prevented me from proceeding with the installation of any plugins.

Comment: I doubt you made the necessary selections since you refused not to select all listed at the top. In the preferences _Update/Install > Available Software Sites_ remove the non eclipse.org update sites you do not trust or do not need anymore and try again. You checked _Always trust all authorities_ (which is not recommended), but didn't _Select All_? That does not make sense at all.

Comment: Thank you! removing the non eclipse update sites made it work! I have actually pressed _Select all_ at that time. (And thank you for informing me about _Always trust all_)